# Prevent angular $http.get from returning 304 response

Tags: angularjs, http, get, http-status-code-304

My backend returns different data for some get requests depending on the user's session data. I would like to force angular to not use cache for certain get requests so that it can retrieve the latest data from the server. I have tried a few things but I keep getting back a 304 not modified response when repeating the same get request. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: HTTP 304 has nothing to do with Angular I suppose, it's Browser behavior. Refer to this [topic](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25342/headers-to-prevent-304-if-modified-since-head-requests) about how to prevent 304

Comment: Add a random query string behind your url, that takes timestamp as the value. This way, each request will be considered a fresh one

Comment: Yep, adding time based string ?date=... is easy and works for sure. You can specify cache: false, add headers, etc., but seems IE dont care about it.

Comment: Yep, this was the only method that I could get to work